# What is the reason (necessity) behind using tautologies in propositional logic proofs and inference?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the reason (necessity) behind using tautologies in propositional logic proofs and inference?
And why do we only talk about $\rightarrow$ connective when talking about inference or proofs? In fact there are 16 of them including $(and, or, xor, and, T, ...)$.

Comment: Who's "we", and which tautologies are you using, and how do you define "tautology"? If it's a proposition true by mere logic, quite some part (some say, all) of mathematics would consist of tautologies.

Comment: @K.Smith  Can you please give some specific examples of what you are talking about?

Comment: @Bram28 sorry for the confusion. My main question is why do we use only a subset of propositions namely "tautologies" as the rules of inference when we want to go from axioms to a theorem? Please correct me if I am wrong since I am new to this subject.

Comment: The reason $\implies$ is taken as a primitive is because it is supposed to reflect the fundamental "step" in proof.  "I know $X$, the logic runs its gears and generates $Y$ as something we also know now" is represented $X \vdash Y$.  It is a bit of a reflective statement then to say $X \implies Y$ is a statement not only about the logic, but a statement provable in the logic.

Comment: @DanielV Thanks Daniel, but why would X⟹Y reflect X⊢Y? Is it because of its truth table, if so why?

Comment: @K.Smith It is designed with that intent (at least in a Hilbert System which is what you seem to be describing).  The axioms and inferences are specifically chosen to make $(\vdash A \to B) \text{ iff } (A \vdash B)$.

Comment: @DanielV I see, but why the intent was such? Is there a reason behind that or it was just an arbitrary choice?

Comment: @K.Smith have you yet solved the question? I have the same problem you're asking. The answers are good but didn't make me clear the thing with tautologies. Why they are used in the first place, what was the reason of their appearance, etc. It's like obvious thing all people talking about but for me it's not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are confusing tautologies with deductively valid inference rules.  An inference rule like Modus Ponens says that $\psi$ can be inferred from $\varphi$ and $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$.  It can be represented as $\varphi, \varphi \rightarrow \psi \vdash \psi$, or maybe as $\varphi, \varphi \rightarrow \psi \Rightarrow \psi$, but it is not a tautology. There is a tautology associated with it though, which would be $(\varphi \land (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow \psi$. Indeed, with every inference rule we can associate some conditional.... maybe this is what you are looking at?

Comment: I think i can see a mistake in your answer: should not "(φ∧(φψ))→ψ" instead be "(φ∧(φ→ψ))→ψ"?

Comment: @user400188. Thanks for your edit! :)

Comment: Thanks Bram. But doesn't that mean tautologies and deductive valid reference rules are somehow the same?

Comment: Or let me ask it another way. What is the difference between φ,φ→ψ⇒ψ and  (φ∧(φ→ψ))→ψ really?

Comment: @K.Smith The first one is an inference ... it says what the user of that proof system is allowed to infer from what.  The second is a tautology ... a statement that is always true. And yes, it is true that any inference is deductively valid inference if and only if its corresponding conditional is a tautology ... but they are still different things.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusion in your question. One of the core issue, though, is that you have a very narrow view of what logic is because you likely haven't been taught any other perspectives, and you're assuming that that narrow perspective covers the entire field.

In particular, I suspect you've only seen [Hilbert style proof systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) for classical logic (and possibly only classical propositional logic). A Hilbert-style proof system for a propositional logic consists of one rule of inference, modus ponens, and a variety of axioms primarily in terms of the connective $\to$ because that's what modus ponens talks about. This approach is fairly minimalistic (which makes it nice when you want to prove (meta-)theorems *about* the system), but is fairly unstructured providing little guidance on what a "good" collection of axioms would be. (Obviously, this isn't a problem when you are just handed the axioms.)

There are other approaches to proof systems, most notably [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) and the [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus). These approaches tend to have many rules of inference and few, if any, axioms. In these systems, there's nothing particularly special about $\to$. Indeed, if you wanted to, you could take the rules of inference from these systems and build your own "Hilbert-like" system based on $\{\neg,\land\}$ instead of $\to$ (or really, it's closer to $\{\neg,\to\}$ or $\{\bot,\to\}$ for the "usual" Hilbert-style system). One of the key things Gentzen accomplished with natural deduction and the sequent calculus is making the logical connectives modular. That is, the rules of inference in these systems characterizing $\land$, say, don't depend on the other logical connectives or, very much, on the properties of the resulting logic.

This leads into the fact that there are (many) other logics besides classical propositional logic. Logical connectives are not Boolean functions, and there's an unlimited number of them. It is a *meta-theorem* that you can relate propositional functions to Boolean functions in classical propositional logic (the soundness and completeness theorems). The logic and its models are different things. Indeed, if we slightly tweak classical propositional logic to [intuitionistic propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus), it is no longer the case that Boolean functions are complete models for it. Similarly, if we add logical connectives like quantifiers or [modalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), Boolean functions are no longer even a model of these system, let alone a sound and complete one. It pays to keep the distinction between syntax and semantics clear in your mind, and to understand that there isn't just One True Logic. There are many, many different, often incomparable, logics.

It should be clear at this point that 1) the focus of Hilbert-style systems on $\to$ is ultimately arbitrary, there are reasons one would make this choice as opposed to others, as DanielV's comment alludes to, but other choices can be made; and 2) the existence of certain Boolean functions is not that relevant to whether something is, or should be, a logical connective especially once we go beyond classical logics.

As for tautologies, we don't use them in proofs and inference; we use (only) axioms and rules of inference for proofs and inference. Tautologies are what proofs prove. From a formal perspective, "tautology" and "theorem" are more or less synonymous. When you use a tautology in an informal proof, you can either view it as you are working in a system where that tautology is an axiom/rule of inference, or you can view it as simply a reference to a proof done before, i.e. if you were to formalize the proof you would need to inline the proofs of any tautologies you used with the resulting proof consisting only of axioms and rules of inference. Some systems, like the sequent calculus, explicitly have rules of inference for reusing previously proved theorems: [the cut rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_rule). Modus ponens itself is closely related to a special case of the cut rule, and also captures to some extent this idea of reusing previously proved results, which is another reason it was chosen as the primary rule of Hilbert-style proof systems.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I think I will take me sometime to go through your reply and digest it.

Comment: Do you know of any resource (preferably brief one) which gives you an overview and bird eyes view of the whole logical and inferential systems? Because like you said the problem is that most of the resources talk only about part of the whole thing called logic. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Smith Logic is a large, open-ended, actively growing field, so there is nothing like a single, comprehensive resource, brief or otherwise. The Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy [has 42 articles](https://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html#l) under the heading "logic". I recommend just sampling from them. The SEP usually has reasonable articles, though it's coming from a philosophy perspective. Most of what I mentioned roughly falls under structural proof theory, but proof theory, type theory, set theory, model theory, category theory, and computability theory are highly relevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

An answer at the basic level.

Suppose that, from premise (~A --> B) and ~B , you want to derive : A OR (~B <-->C) .

You will you OR-introduction rule: "from X, infer X OR Y".

This rule belongs to syntax: it tells you what you can write after what, which concatenation of symbols is correct.

~A --> B

~ B

~ ~ A ( by modus tollens)

A  ( by double negation)

A OR ( ~B <--> C)

***Now, you may ask yourself the question : what guarantees this OR introduction rule?***

By asking this question, you refer to the semantic notion of validity : you are wondering what makes sure that  the proposition A OR ( ~B <--> C)  can never be false when A is true.

But this last question is the same as :

- what guarantees that "A OR ( ~B <--> C)" is always true when A is true?
- what guaranties that, in all possible cases : IF A is true, THEN A OR ( ~B <--> C) is also true?

And at this point you will appreciate this semantic notion of " tautology".

You can safely infer A OR ( ~B <--> C) from A, because, generally speaking,

X --> (X OR Y)

is a tautology, that is, a formula that is true in all possible cases ( truth value assignments).